# replacing field name suffixes in bulk

Tags: sas

I have a dataset where I have several variables with suffixes that correspond to given dates. I want to replace the suffixes with the dates to make my output tables more user friendly.

Here is a sample of my code

the fields in my `sales` dataset are
`product` `number_of_sales_1` `number_of_sales_2` `number_of_sales_3` `revenue_1` `revenue_2` `revenue_3` `tax_1` `tax_2` `tax_3`

The suffixes 1,2,3 correspond to dates which are held in a second dataset with the following format

`dates`

`id` `date`

`1`  `01Apr`

`2`  `01May`

`3`  `01Jun`

I want to bulk replace the suffixes with the dates so my fields in `sales` become

`product` `number_of_sales_01Apr` `number_of_sales_01May` `number_of_sales_01Jun` `revenue_01Apr` `revenue_01May` `revenue_01Jun` `tax_01Apr` `tax_01May` `tax_01Jun`

Both the number of dates and the numberof metrics in `sales` are dynamic so I can't just hardcode in the the code.

Comment: I would suggest using labels instead, you get a display value but variable names that are easier to type and list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume your datasets look like below:

```
data sales;
product="abc";number_of_sales_1=1;number_of_sales_2=2;number_of_sales_3=3;
revenue_1=1000;revenue_2=2000;revenue_3=3000;tax_1=100;tax_2=200;tax_3=300;
run;

data dates;
id=1;date="01Apr";output;id=2;date="01May";output;id=3;date="01Jun";output;
run;
```

- 1st Step - Finding out the dates variables which needs to be renamed

---

```
proc contents data=sales out=sales_temp(keep=name) noprint;  run;

data sales_temp1;
length check_date_vars $1. id 8.;
set sales_temp;
check_date_vars=compress(substr(name,length(name)));
temp=notdigit(check_date_vars);
if temp=0 then id=check_date_vars;
run;
```

- 2nd step - Merging the above dataset with the datset which contains the formats, to create a mapping between old names and new names and creating macro variables out of it

---

```
proc sort data=sales_temp1;    by id;    run;

proc sort data=dates;    by id;    run;

data sales_temp_date;
merge sales_temp1(in=a) dates(in=b);
by id;
if a and b;
new_name=substr(name,1,length(name)-1)||date;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :num_vars separated by " " from sales_temp_date;
quit;

proc sql noprint;
select name into:old_name1 - :old_name&num_vars.  from sales_temp_date;
select new_name into:new_name1 - :new_name&num_vars. from sales_temp_date;
quit;
```

- 3rd Step - Renaming the variables

---

```
 %macro rename();
proc datasets library=work nolist;
modify sales;
rename 
%do i=1 %to &num_vars.;
 &&old_name&i.= &&new_name&i.
%end;
;
run;
%mend;
%rename;
```